# Getting times from MySQL for use in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

In my mySQL table I have two columns "Time A" (**DateTime**) and "Time B" (**TimeStamp**) and each row of the represents a different user. I would like to get the difference between Time A and B for all users in the table.

Would it be better to do most of it in PHP (what the majority of the project I'm working on is in) use a query to retrieve the columns and use something like: `$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );` to get the same format, store in 2 arrays for timeA and B and calculate the difference for each of the positions in the arrays

Or is there a quicker/more efficient way to do this throw a single MySQL query where the result is the time differences for each row? If that is possible any pointers would be appreciated.

The question is; what is the best approach here PHP or a mysql query. The reason I am stuck is because there could be a lot of rows to be handled and unsure of which direction to go.

edit - Example table StartDuration is Time A and End Duration is Time B 
[image: Example table]

Ideal output would be a return time for each row so i could use

`While($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$timeDiff[] = $row[result]`
}

to store all the result times for each user in an array.

Comment: it should be possible in MySQL only with a co-related subqeury and correct indexing.. might somebody can give a example query if you could share your table structure and some example data ascii data based table.. also post the excepted output also as ascii data based table..

Comment: based on the comment on tenflex's anser you've not explained the problem - voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have ended up using was this.

```
$query = "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`TimeA`,`TimeB`) 
FROM Table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $time[] = $row['TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`TimeA`,`TimeB`)'];
}
```

My confusion, the reason I posted the question, was mainly with the compatibility of the different MySql methods to compare times and the data types of the columns. But this has worked for me

Answer (score 0):

just run it all in SQL like

```
Select 
    (CAST (table.time_a AS TIMESTAMP) - table.time_b) as timestampDiff 
from table;
```

Comment: this won't compare between records.

Comment: then the question becomes ambigous. what is the inter-row comparison criterion.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Who said they needed to be compared?

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEDIFF() or TIMEDIFF(), depending on if you want difference in days, or exact time difference.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(`Time A`, `Time B`) as difference FROM table;
```

Comment: this won't compare between records.

Comment: He said has has columns though, not Rows? This will work between columns

Comment: "single MySQL query where the result is the time differences for each row?"

Comment: "In my mySQL table I have two columns "Time A" (DateTime) and "Time B" (TimeStamp) and each row of the represents a different user. I would like to get the difference between Time A and B for all users in the table.". I suppose the question isn't 100% clear.

Comment: maybe we are both right.. normally you shouldn't post a answer on MySQL questions without example table/example data and expected output.

Comment: I will add example table and expected output